# Filter the $(this) element in loop jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to perform an action to other elements than the `$(this)` item

```
$('.items').click(function(){

    var myitem = $(this);

    $(".items").each(function() {

        if (myitem == $(this)){
            break;
        } else {
            //perform action
        }

    });
});
```

Where did I go wrong? Is there any better method?

Comment: Don't you have added different ids in every element with having same class `items`. If you have added ids then you can also check for ids. So you simply skip the clicked elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `.not()` function to filter out the current element,

```
$('.items').click(function(){
  $('.items').not(this).each(function(){
    //perform action here.
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**What went wrong?**

When using the `jQuery` method (a.k.a. `$`) a new instance of the jQuery *object* is created, containing a list of *elements* matching your selector along side with a rich *prototype* of jQuery's methods.

Your mistake was to try and compare two **different** instances.

What you could have done was to compare the *elements* themselves by making the following changes:

```
// change this:
var myitem = $(this);
// to this:
var myitem = this;

// change this:
if (myitem == $(this)){
// to this:
if (myitem == this){
```

Unless you intend to use the jQuery *object* functionality there's no reason to initiate a new instance. Simply use the *element* itself when possible. It's a best practice to avoid such use cases. Performance wise.

**Best solution**

But the best solution in your case is what was mentioned in all other answers, using jQuery's [not](http://api.jquery.com/%3anot/) method to exclude the *element* from the newly created instance.

Comment: Nice answer +1., also he shouldnt use "break;" in his code. Which will cause the loop to exit.

Answer (score 0):

Using`.not()` to avoid

Try this

```
$(".items").not($(this)).each(function() {


});
```

OR

As per your code

```
$(".items").not(myitem).each(function() {


});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `not()` to ignore the element which is clicked:

```
$(".items").not(this).each(function() {

});
```

Comment: Don't you mean `$(this)` instead of `this`?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad why $(this)? I thing 'this' alone is enough

Comment: Both would do the job, but creating a list instance it redundant in this case.

Comment: sorry @iMoses did'nt got you

Comment: When using the `jQuery` method (a.k.a. `$`) a new instance of `jQuery` is created, containing a list of elements matching your selector. There's absolutely no reason to do so and it would be a best practice to avoid such use cases. Performance wise.